# Binding ListView SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF application that has a ListView with several Image sources loaded into it. How can I bind the selected image so it is displayed in a larger viewing area that is contained within a Grid?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code I am working with:

```
    <Window x:Class="ListViewImageSelection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400">

<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="bike"   UriSource="Images/bike.bmp"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="car"    UriSource="Images/car.bmp"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="flower" UriSource="Images/flower.bmp"/>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



    <ListView Name="MyListView" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.PanningMode="VerticalOnly">
        <Image Source="{StaticResource bike}" Width="110" />
        <Image Source="{StaticResource car}" Width="110" />
        <Image Source="{StaticResource flower}" Width="110" />
    </ListView>

    <Image Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Uniform"  Source="{Binding ElementName=MyListView, Path=SelectedItem.ImageUri}"/>


</Grid>
```

Comment: @Joe I tried your suggestion, but couldn't get it to work. I posted my code, can you take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Image Source="{Binding ElementName=MyListView, Path=SelectedItem.ImageUri}"/>
```

Comment: @ScanMan happy to hear So please Mark as answered. I thought that your are binding it to your objects ImageUri Property